# Google Pie Chart and Bar Chart (both Interactive) not showing labels

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8, google-visualization, pie-chart, bar-chart

I'm trying to put Google's [BarChart](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/barchart.html) and [PieChart](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/piechart.html) both the client side version, and i'm experiencing some problems with the *labels over the pie* and the *labels on the left of the vertical axis* (of the bar chart).

I checked the code a lot of times and it seems to be like that you can see in the examples.
I've tried the same page on Firefox and Chrome and it shows the labels without problems.

If i try the examples on IE8 the labels are shown but not in my page.

Sincerely I've not any idea where to start to fix this thing.

Someone can help me or give me an advice?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want there is a library for fusion charts and asp.net at

http://liberofusioncharts.codeplex.com

[image]

Fusion chart is richer in options....

Comment: Thanks for the advice... But I was trying to use this type of charts because one of my objectives is to put the elaboration and render of the chart on the client.